# With bootstrap trying to toggle div with a select option menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use bootstrap's data-toggle in combo with a select option menu but i can't get it to work

Here's my menu

```
<select name="sort" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                        <option value="">---</option>
                        <option  selected='selected' value="uniform"  data-toggle="#uniOptions">Uniform</option>
                        <option  value="eigen"  data-toggle="#customOptions" >Custom</option>
                    </select>
```

and html

```
 <div id="uniOptions" style="display: none;">
......
</div>
 <div id="customOptions" style="display: none;">
......
</div>
```

here's part of the javascript

```
.find('option[data-toggle]')
        .on('click', function() {
            var $target = $($(this).attr('data-toggle'));
            // Show or hide the additional fields
            // They will or will not be validated based on their visibilities
            $target.toggle();
            if (!$target.is(':visible')) {
                // Enable the submit buttons in case additional fields are not valid
                $('#togglingForm').data('bootstrapValidator').disableSubmitButtons(false);
            }
        });
```

but option[data-toggle] doesn't work

Also tried

```
.find('option[data-toggle]')
            .on('change', function() {
```

Any tips, suggestions?